# While zoom in zoomout needle was moved y axis side in Gauge Highcharts in Browser

Tags: highcharts, gauge

Here My Screenshot please find below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZY4Z.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/uj2oe3ky/

```
Assist Me
```

Comment: Witch browser are you using? I checked on my devices and everything is working well.

Comment: i am using google chrome

Comment: In which version of the Chrome version? I can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: One more issue also Sebastian when i minimize and maximize chart was not render above code. showing empty charts

Comment: Could you make a gif with the whole path of your case? It would help to check it out better.